# What does it mean to register the half-radishes?

Tags: meaning

In his description of meanness, Theophrastus says:

" Entertaining his clansmen, he will beg a dish from the common table for his own servants; and will register the half-radishes leftover from the repast, in order that the attendants may not get them. "

What does it mean to register the half-radishes leftover from the meal ( repast )?

Apart from that, why does this count as mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this puzzling? He’s keeping track of leftover food so the servers (staff) can’t eat it or take it for their families, even something so minor as half a radish.

Comment: And this is *mean* in the adjectival sense (per *[American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mean))* of “3. Miserly; stingy.” The “meanness” of the sketch's title is in the original [αἰσχροκέρδεια](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ai%29sxroke%2Frdeia%2F&la=greek&can=ai%29sxroke%2Frdeia%2F0), "sordid love of gain, base covetousness."